# How can I namespace my labels in codewarrior

Tags: assembly, codewarrior, 68hc12

I have three files, an .asm file and some .inc files. They are both being included with `include`. In these files there are labels, and I would like to be able to sometimes use the same label in each. For example, if each included file has a loop, then I would like to label the loops `loop` and be done with it. This is a problem for the assembler though, as the labels are not unique.

In codewarrior's help file I read that I could add `\@` to the beginning of a label in a macro to avoid multiple calls to that macro resulting in the labels conflicting. I tried that though and the assembler complained (`invalid character detected at the beginning of the line`). Is there a way of namespacing my labels?

Thanks,

z.

ps also, I included the word codewarrior in the question, which is my IDE. I did this because I'm not sure whether the treatment of labels is specific to an assembler or to the IDE itself. Did I need to say "codewarrior" or would I have been better off saying "HC12" or just "assembly"? Thanks.

pps this is homework: but my homework is to write code, not to namespace labels.

Comment: For now I am just doing it myself: SUMloop, SFTloop, etc...